# Should I rephrase my question through Edits or delete it and start over?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it better to start over again if the question is in some way flawed or should I just edit the question (including title and description) so that the earlier discussion is preserved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only if the Edits to the question are going to change the questions entirely, should you close the question and make a new one.

If you edit is expanding on the question by providing more information, clarifying unclear language, or updating obvious Typos or mistake you should edit it. That's the purpose of the editing functionality.

Comment: Even when the edits *do* change the question entirely, it's preferable to make them (instead of starting a new thread) provided nobody has yet answered the question.

Comment: Also whenever there is an Edit please update the reason for edit so that the cause can be understood and there is a track of what the edits were made